# pom.xml <parent> and <properies>

Tags: maven

When I make `<parent>` configuration use properties it stops working

```
<properties>
    <springboot.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</springboot.version>
</properties> 

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

And it works fine when I set `<version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>`. What is the problem here?

Comment: please add the error message to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a property for the version of the parent within the `<parent>` tag in the child module.

Maven has the feature, that properties are inherited from a parent to its children. For achieving this, maven has to resolve the parent first, and then the properties (inherited or not) are resolved. That means, maven will not resolve a property within the `<parent>` tag.

Within the childs coordinates, you can ommit the version and the groupId, if it makes sense in your use case. These informations are inherited from the parents pom, but can be overridden in the child.

```xml
<project>
    <parent>
         <groupId>your.company</groupId>
         <artifactId>companyParent</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.4</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- child coordinates -->
    <!-- version and groupId are inherited -->
    <artifactId>childA</artifactId>
    ....
</project>
```